# Django template: pass a variable to view {{ dic.{{ a.d }} }}

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Django template: pass a variable to view `{{ dic.{{ a.d }} }}` // Access a dictionary

I need to pass a variable to dic, and this variable come from `{{ a.d }}`

So, what is the best way to do that?

Ok, I need to look up a dictionary.

{{ a.d }} returns a key.

so {{ dic.key }} will work.

Comment: Could you please explain a little better, what are you trying to do? 'Cause I didn't really understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% with a.d as key %}
 ...
  {{ dic.key }}
 ...
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: By the way, is there any way to access the list element in django template? Eg. lst[3]

Comment: I can understand `with` being a bit hard to find, but... http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables